# Pfsense HAproxy redirect loop

Tags: linux, haproxy, pfsense

I've made a mistake when adding backend prop to HAproxy in pfsense. I made an entry like so: `http-request redirect prefix / code 301` amd my pfsense is now in infinite redirect loop. Any tips how to unlock it ?